# Shell script Bash, Check if string starts and ends with single quotes

Tags: bash, shell

I need to check if a string starts and ends with a single quote, for example
'My name is Mozart'

What I have is this, which doesn't work

```
if [[ $TEXT == '*' ]] ;
```

This does not work either

```
if [[ $TEXT == /'*/' ]] ;
```

But if I change it to

```
if [[ $TEXT == a*a ]] ;
```

it works for a sentence like 'an amazing apa'. So I Believe it has to do with the single quote sign.

Any ideas on how I can solve it?

Comment: Explanation for a*a is: 
a* matches the character a literally (case sensitive)
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
a matches the character a literally (case sensitive)

I will match any a in the text

Comment: did you solve your  problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am writing the complete bash script so you won't have any confusion:

```
#! /bin/bash
text1="'helo there"
if [[ $text1 =~ ^\'.*\'$ ]]; then
        echo "text1 match"
else
        echo "text1 not match"

fi

text2="'hello babe'"
if [[ $text2 =~ ^\'.*\'$ ]]; then
        echo "text2 match"
else
        echo "text2 not match"
fi
```

Save the above script as 
`matchCode.sh`

Now run it as: 
`./matchCode`

output:

```
text1 not match
text2 match
```

Ask if you have any confusion.

Comment: I think your solution would be more readable if you put the check in an extra function. That way you don't have duplicate code and people can grasp what the solution does at first glance.

Answer (score 16):

With a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
if [[ $TEXT =~ ^\'.*\'$ ]]
```

With [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29):

```
if [[ $TEXT == \'*\' ]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but none of them are working

Comment: @chichi: These are valid Bash solutions. Run `[[ "'ab'" =~ ^\'.*\'$ ]] && echo yes` and `[[ "'ab'" == \'*\' ]] && echo yes` in your shell. Unless both of them output `yes`, you must be using a shell other than Bash.

Answer (score 5):

[Cyrus' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40317633/45375) solves your problem *as posted*.

However, I suspect **you may be confused over quotes that are *part of the shell syntax* vs. quotes that are actually *part of the string***:

- In a POSIX-like shell such as Bash, `'My name is Mozart'` is a single-quoted string whose content is the literal `My name is Mozart` - *without* the enclosing `'`. That is, the enclosing  `'` characters are a *syntactic elements* that tell the shell that everything *between* them is the *literal contents* of the string.
- By contrast, to create a string whose *content* is actually enclosed in `'` - i.e., has *embedded* `'` instances, you'd have to use something like: `"'My name is Mozart'"`. Now it is the enclosing `"` instances that are the syntactic elements that bookend the string content.

  - Note, however, that using a `"..."` string (double quotes) makes the contents subject to [*string interpolation*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) (expansion of embedded variable references, arithmetic and command substitutions; none in the case at hand, however), so it's important to know when to use `'...'` (literal strings) vs. `"..."` (interpolated strings).
  - Embedding `'` instances in `'...'` strings is actually not supported at all in POSIX-like shells, but in Bash, Ksh, and Zsh there's another string type that allows you to do that: [ANSI C-quoted strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), `$'...'`, in which you can embed `'` escaped as `\'`: `$'\'My name is Mozart\''`
  - Another option is to use string *concatenation*: In POSIX-like shells, you can place substrings employing different quoting styles (including unquoted tokens) *directly* next to one another in order to form a single string: `"'"'My Name is Mozart'"'"` would also give you a string with *contents* `'My Name is Mozart'`.
    POSIX-like shells also allow you to escape *individual, unquoted characters* (meaning: neither part of a single- nor a double-quoted string) with `\`; therefore, `\''My name is Mozart'\'` yields the same result.

---

The **behavior of Bash's `==` operator inside `[[ ... ]]` (conditionals)** may have added to the confusion:

If the RHS (right-hand side - the operand to the right of operator `==`) is *quoted*, Bash treats it like a *literal*; only *unquoted* strings (or variable references) are treated as (glob-like) *patterns*:

`'*'` matches *literal* `*`, whereas `*` (unquoted!) matches any sequence of characters, including none.

Thus:

- `[[ $TEXT == '*' ]]` would only ever match the *single, literal character `*`*.
- `[[ $TEXT == /'*/' ]]`, because it mistakes `/` for the escape character - which in reality is `\` - would only match *literal* `/*/` (`/'*/'` is effectively a concatenation of unquoted `/` and single-quoted literal `*/`).
- `[[ $TEXT == a*a ]]`, due to using an *unquoted* RHS, is the only variant that actually performs *pattern matching*: any string that starts with `a` and ends with `a` is matched, including `aa` (because unquoted `*` represents any sequence of characters).

---

To verify that Cyrus' commands do work with strings whose *content* is enclosed in (embedded) single quotes, try these commands, which - on Bash, Ksh, and Zsh - should both output `yes`.

```
[[ "'ab'" == \'*\' ]] && echo yes  # pattern matching, indiv. escaped ' chars.

[[ "'ab'" =~ ^\'.*\'$ ]] && echo yes # regex operator =~
```